# I read that clearMarkers() was depricated for flutter Google maps

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have been looking for a way to clear all markers on my flutter Google map, I read somewhere that mapcontroller.clearMarkers() ; was depricated and when I use it now it says Google map controller doesnt have that function defined, so any suggestions on what to use to clear all markers on my map? Please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set a set of markers to use in the Maps

```
 Set<Marker> _markers = {
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433).toString()),
      position: LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: 'Tommy\'s Home',
        snippet: 'Very cool place',
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    )
};
```

Inside the Map:

```
GoogleMap(
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
     target: _center,
     zoom: 11.0,
  ),
  mapType: MapType.hybrid,
  markers: _markers,
),
```

Then setting it to empty will do the trick:

```
setState(){
   _markers = {};
}
```